# Serialized Protobufs have nullbyte and cannot be sent by ZMQ

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I am currently trying to send some protobufs using zmq and so far this has worked great. Now I started a different ( and more complicated ) protobuf and it stopped working.

I already found the error, which is that a de-serialization of the protobuf-object creates a string containing the nullbyte `\0`.

**EDIT:**
I think I've found the cause. In `zmq_send` there is a line, where `memcpy` is being called. Since everything after `\0` is supposedly not accessible, I get an error. Still no idea what to do.

So far I haven't come up with a solution to this problem, do you guys have an idea?

Comment: Protobuf is a binary serializer and is perfectly entitled to use 0 bytes - it is guaranteed to do so for a range of values. Basically: don't use string APIs when working with binary data - you'll need to use binary safe APIs throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, show you code. It is not clear what do you do and what expect to get. Neither protobuf nor zmq are not bound to ASCIIZ. The following sample sequence works fine for any kind of data within protobuf structure pb

```
reqSize = pb->ByteSize();
reqBuf = new char [reqSize];
pb->SerializeToArray(reqBuf, reqSize);
zmq_send(zc, reqBuf, reqSize, 0);
```